# Query String Parameter Encryption/Decryption? Usabe with Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, encryption, query-string

I have an instance where an external source is going to pop a browser that will navigate to my host page for my Silverlight application.
Within the query string that third party is sending pseudo-sensitive data that I do not want the user to be able to manipulate.
Seeing the data itself isn't the issue, it's simply being able to increment or change the values to assumed values.

My issue is that most cryptography I've found is not usable in Silverlight to decrypt the query string values.

I have 3 query string parameters that need encrypted.

i.e.

3rd Party: (encrypted values would need to be value1, 2 and 3)

```
//make call to Silverlight application host page
http://server/SilverlightRIA.aspx?value1=blah&value2=foo&value3=bar
```

My application's ASPX page will strip the query string parameters and send them to the Silverlight application through init parameters.
At this point they can be decrypted and set as globals variables or whatever the case may be.

I'm hoping for some suggestions on the best way or most efficient/simplest way to encrypt the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually ended up finding a fairly simple encryption method that will work with Silverlight.